# Good system for writing coding excerpts (possible cloud based)

Tags: cloud, source-code, usability, notes

I am using Ubuntu for some time, and 99% of time I am using Goggle drive Documents for writing code excerpts.

However, Google experience, although super fast when searching, works quite slow when opening Google docs. My documents are not big, likely 5k.

The other problem is that I cannot format `PHP` and or `JavaScript` code in Google docs.

What do you suggest I can use that may sit well with Ubuntu? I know Ubuntu has some clouds, but I need free system that just works for making notes.

Lastly, it may not be on the cloud at all. My problem is I sticked to make notes on Google drive, and I now would like to recall.

Comment: what is wrong with gedit?

Comment: if my computer dies, so my notes may...

Comment: And that's why you create backups.  Online or on an USB. Or something else. Have every file edited directly synched to a 2nd place not on your actual computer using a date stamp. Easy to setup. Works perfectly.

Comment: nice, but will try to evaluate if there is something super cool that would turn me on instantly, since I am very lazy, and tend to forget things, and sometime I even work on more then one comp...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cool thing I just found are Github gists.
There can be secret or public gists. And they support php code syntax.
https://gist.github.com/